# how could a creature have a vacuum chamber inside its body

Tags: science-based, biology, xenobiology, chemistry, biochemistry

i want to know how an animal could have a vacuum inside itself (in an organ), survive, and also for it to be stable, what materials could be used to contain it, and how could it be implemented without changing much of the shape of an animal, and any other data you want to give etc.

thank you very much, this is also in an earth-like enviroment

edit:the purpose is to reduce weight, and yes, the vacuum grows with the animal, which is a flying lizard

edit:the creature is born without an actual vacuum, but it has the chamber, it just needs to make it a vacuum

Comment: Any idea of a specific animal type? Aquatic, land based? Mammal, insect...? There are a lot of possibilities, so the question is a bit broad to give the answer you want to read about :).

Comment: When you inspire air into your lungs what you do is use the intercostal and abdominal muscles to expand the thoracic cavity; this create a partial vacuum in the lungs, and the exterior atmospheric pressure pushes air in. If you block your nose, close your mouth and try to inspire, what you get is a partial vacuum in the lungs. The point being that humans (and most land animals) already *have* "vacuum chambers" inside their bodies.... I take it that this is not what you wanted?

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise. What do you mean by vacuum inside? Is the entire animal "empty", is it an organ? how big is that organ. What is the environment? "Earth-like" can mean a variety of environment - is it a land animal, an airborne animal or an aquatic one?

Comment: A permanent stable vacuum inside the creature’s body. How big does the chamber need to be? How big is the creature? It’s a good question, but it needs details before being answered.

Comment: Not likely. Even if you have a vacuum inside a dense bone structure, the surrounding tissue will outgass into the vacuum, slowly making it non-so-vacuum.

Comment: Why is is necessary for this creature to be a vacuum bottle?

Comment: And how good a vacuum is needed? If just a bubble of lower pressure (say 1/2 atmosperic), that is much more achievable. Still difficult though.

Comment: Does it need to grow with the creature? Even if it's made of amorphous silica (which some Earth creatures make), helium will still seep-in between the molecules (it does that) so how much of a vacuum does it need to be?

Comment: I had to VTC. Dexyan, remember that you should be asking only one question, it should be as specific as possible and provide as many details as you can. In this case, what kind of animal? What's the intended purpose of the vacuum? Given that genetic engineering is still more fiction than fact, what are you expecting when you ask "how could it be made?"

Comment: Hello, could you tell me if the lizards could come from a genetically enhanced lizard that has had a vacuum and passes it on to it's sucesors?

Comment: even a vacuum does not add noticeable buoyancy to a creature unless is is many times the creatures size. you are only looking at offsetting 1.3 grams per liter of vacuum. or to put it visually this man needs the the tank next to him full of vacuum to just reach zero weight. https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1gZW1j8DH8KJjy1zeq6xjepXaX/Rotational-high-quality-poly-pe-plastic-5000.jpg

Answer (score 3):

**A rigid [swim bladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swim_bladder) would do the trick**

Fish already have an organ that allows them to control their floatation called a swim bladder.  In fish, it's basically a ballon, but if the bladder covered bone with only a small opening, it would likely be able to hold a low-pressure region relative to the outside.

Mythbusters tested if you could cause a [container train car to implode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpWeU2fvFGs&ab_channel=TheScienceist) with a vacuum and succeeded with a damaged one, so if you wanted larger forces in play you'd have to go with something stronger than bone.

Comment: thank you very much